# Interpretation of confidence interval from multivariate analysis

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, multivariate-analysis

Could you help me interpret the predictive variables from the table below taken from an article on preterm labor?

I am trying to understand whether it is accurate to call 'non-significant' the variables with confidence intervals (CI) around 1. For instance, the variable "infertility" has a CI between 0.8-1.9 . Does that mean that infertility is not significant and thus not a predictor of preterm birth? Same for the variable "in vitro fertilization".

Thanks for your input![image]